# Add a json attribute in a flow content with Jolt Transformation or alternative way in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to add this attribute named 'metadata' to json flow content.

The attribute 'metadata' is like:

```json
{"startTime":1451952013663, "endTime":1453680013663, "name":"Npos19", "deleted":false}
```

The input is like this:

```json
{
  "id": 154299613718447,
  "values": [
    {
       "timestamp": 1451977869683,
        "value": 13.1
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1453949805784,
      "value": 7.54
    }
 ]
}
```

My goal is like:

```json
{
  "id": 154299613718447,
  "values": [ { 
      "startTime":1451952013663, 
      "endTime":1453680013663, 
      "name":"Npos19", 
      "deleted":false,
      "timestamp": 1451977869683,
      "value": 13.1
    },
    {  
      "startTime":1451952013663, 
      "endTime":1453680013663, 
      "name":"Npos19", 
      "deleted":false,
      "timestamp": 1453949805784,
      "value": 7.54
    }
 ]
}
```

I tried to use the Jolt Transformation:

```
{
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
     // extract metadata array from json attribute and put it in a temporary array
     "tempArray": "${metadata:jsonPath('$.*')}"
    }
  }
```

but it does not work. I need to extract metadata array with $.* because I do not know what keys will be present.

Is there an alternative fast way with other nifi processors to merge the attribute with flow content?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with combination of two processors: `EvaluateJsonPath` ->`ScriptedTransformRecord`.

**EvaluateJsonPath**

- `Destination`: `flowfile-attribute`
- `Return Type`: `json`
- `values` (dynamic property): `$.values`

**ScriptedTransformRecord**

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Script Language`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```
def mapMetadata = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(attributes['metadata'])
def mapValue = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(attributes['values'])

def values = mapValue.each { value ->
    mapMetadata.each { k, v ->
        value."${k}" = v
    }
}

record.setValue('values', null)
record.setValue('updateValues', values)
record
```

**Output json**

```json
[ {
  "id" : 154299613718447,
  "values" : null,
  "updateValues" : [ {
    "timestamp" : 1451977869683,
    "value" : 13.1,
    "startTime" : 1451952013663,
    "endTime" : 1453680013663,
    "name" : "Npos19",
    "deleted" : false
  }, {
    "timestamp" : 1453949805784,
    "value" : 7.54,
    "startTime" : 1451952013663,
    "endTime" : 1453680013663,
    "name" : "Npos19",
    "deleted" : false
  } ]
} ]
```

Comment: I think it's very slow... I will use big data

Comment: @Alex check https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.15.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ScriptedTransformRecord/additionalDetails.html section Performance Considerations